# how to convert youtube stream url in form of docs.google.com

Tags: youtube-api

I saw different sites who are giving an option to download youtube videos from licks like docs.google.com and also adding pay option which uses same host name. As youtube is banned in Pakistan so we can play videos with this method, is there any script which offer same result? i use this https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader but it gives url to googlevideos which is also not opening in Pakistan, how to convert its links to docs.google.com?

Comment: What do you have on line 63 of https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader/blob/master/ytdl.user.js ?

Comment: dear actually i want c.docs.google.com in the url instead of googlevideo.com because i want to stream videos in a javascript player

Comment: please if you can help then guide me